# What does redis-trib stand for?

Tags: redis

What does the "trib" in the [redis-trib](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/src/redis-trib.rb) utility stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the programmer was having a bit of fun with that name and meant it to mean **Redistrib**ute.

From the page https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

> ... the Redis Cluster command line utility called redis-trib, a Ruby program executing special commands on instances in order to create new clusters, check or reshard an existing cluster, and so forth.

Since a cluster is sometimes called "distributed computing", the program deals entirely with cluster creation and maintenance, and there is no formal explanation of the name; I believe this to be what the programmer was trying to hint at.

Comment: `redis-redis` would have been worse